# NameError: uninitialized constant PG On Migrating to VPS

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, vps, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I am deploying a Rails app using Capistrano 3.0 to VPS. When I run `cap production deploy` I end up with following error. I am using Postgresql.

```
INFO [356ebea5] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate as deployer@ipaddress
DEBUG [356ebea5] Command: cd /home/deployer/scoutqatar/releases/20150315174921 && ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate )
DEBUG [356ebea5]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [356ebea5]    NameError: uninitialized constant PG
```

It seems I get error during migration.

I have `config/database.yml` file in VPS with following:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: dohaguide_development
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: pass

test: &TEST
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: dohaguide_test
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: pass

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: dohaguide_production
  pool: 5
  username: user    
  password: pass
```

I have created the above databses in VPS.

My `deploy.rb` file contains the following

```
# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

end
```

I have been trying to figure out the cause of error but couldnt find anything wrong.
Could someone please guide me in the correct direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was the db user name was different from the user name that was created for the VPS to deploy.